# access method in child1 component from child2 component

Tags: reactjs, react-native, react-redux, components

Currently I have 3 components: `Child1`, `Child2` and `Parent`. When a button in `Child2` is pressed, I want to call a function in `Child1` component.

This is what I have tried so far but I keep getting error saying

```
this.refs.child.child2Function is not a function
```

What would be the right way to handle such situation (calling a function in one child component from another child component)?

I am also using `redux` in my project. But my `Child2` component is rendered in multiple tabs. So I cannot update the value using `redux` as the value will be updated throughout all the `Child2` component.

**Parent.js**

```
class Parent extends Component{

parentFunction = () => {
    console.log("This line gets printed. But the line below this breaks");
    this.refs.child.child2Function();
}

render() { 
    return (
        <View style={styles.pageContainer}>
             <Child1 ref="child"/>
             <Child2 parentFunc={this.parentFunction}/>
        </View>
 )}
```

**Child2.js**

```
class Child2 extends Component{

render() { 
    return (
        <View style={styles.pageContainer}>
             <Button
                 title="CLICK ME" 
                 onPress={()=>this.props.parentFunc()} />
        </View>
 )}
```

**Child1.js**

```
class Child1 extends Component{

child1Function = () => {
  console.log("Print this");
}

render() { 
    return (
        <View style={styles.pageContainer}>
             <Text>AAAA</Text>
        </View>
 )}
```

**UPDATE:**
Code works properly in the snack example set up here : https://snack.expo.io/rk4Y9RWUm

But I keep getting error when I have similar solution in my react native app. I have included screenshot of my code, console log and error message here : https://drive.google.com/drive/folders/1RQYicEC_wqHKPRCs9pVsMZyuTxyiUbq2?usp=sharing

Comment: why don't you move the `child2Function` into the parent and access it from there in both children?

Comment: Because child2Function updates local states in child2 component. Also this component is used in other different components (basically parent2, parent3, ...)

Comment: what does `console.log(this.refs.child)` print out? Can you setup an example on codepen or something for us to play with?

Comment: I dont see whats wrong? the code works as expected... https://codepen.io/anon/pen/gjJMYQ?editors=0010

Comment: @JohnRuddell I set up a snack example and it works perfectly. But when i do the same this in my react native app, I get an error.
Link to Snack: https://snack.expo.io/rk4Y9RWUm

Link to screenshot of my code, console.log and error message: 
https://drive.google.com/drive/folders/1RQYicEC_wqHKPRCs9pVsMZyuTxyiUbq2?usp=sharing

Comment: Hmm maybe try verifying you created the function in the right way. Your bundler may not accept the lambda syntax for class methods. aka `child1Function = () => {` change to `child1Function() {` and just remember in your constructor to add `this.child1Function = this.child1Function.bind(this)` also try just debugging the issue. add a new line before where it breaks and add `debugger` then look at what this.refs.child is and also what child1Function is too

Comment: I think my bundler does except lambda syntax. I am using lambda syntax almost everywhere else. Anyways I tried with child1Function() {  but still same error as show in screenshot.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/178098/discussion-between-chetan-and-john-ruddell).

Comment: After trying to figure out what's going wrong,I found out that the error message only pop's up when the react native debugger is turned on.

Comment: Saw your invite lastnight. I took a look. It looks like your version of react doensn't expose user defined properties on a react class. I can fix it for you by either upgrading your version of react.. or if you want to change the way you are doing this, use state in the parent class that stores the values and pass to the child. In willReceiveProps you can determine when the prop changes and call a function

Comment: Thanks John. Yes that's the work around I have been using (using state in parent class and passing it to Child component). Just to be sure, is this better than using ref?

Answer (score 0):

You can not invoke a function inside child1 component directly from child2. Because the function inside child1 is encapsulated to child1 component it is not visible from outside. The only way to communicate between two components is through common parent component. You can declare required state and functions inside parent component and pass them as props to the child components. Child components then can share and  change these states through functions passed from parent component. You can share state change between sibling component which share the same parent component. The only way of communication between sibling components is though common Parent component. Here is the link to sample code as an example: https://codesandbox.io/s/wom3622q8

Code sample:import React from "react";

```
const ChildOneComponent ({ number, handleChangeNumber }) => {
  return (
    <div>
      <button onClick={handleChangeNumber}>Change Number</button>
      State in ChildOneComponent is : {number}
    </div>
  );
};
const ChildTwoComponent ({ number, handleChangeNumber }) => {
  return (
    <div>
      <button onClick={handleChangeNumber}>Change Number</button>
      State in ChildTwoComponent is : {number}
    </div>
  );
};


class ParentComponent extends React.Component {
  state = { number: 0 };
  handleChangeNumber = () => {
    let number = this.state.number;
    this.setState(() => ({ number: ++number }));
    console.log("cliked");
  };
  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        <ChildOneComponent
          number={this.state.number}
          handleChangeNumber={this.handleChangeNumber}
        />
        <ChildTwoComponent
          number={this.state.number}
          handleChangeNumber={this.handleChangeNumber}
        />
      </div>
    );
  }
}
```